# Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, c#-3.0

I have recently started a development in c# and want to use reflection in following situation.
If I have a Enum class as

```
Enum Operation
{
  Read=0;
  Write;
}
```

If I give input as

```
String str = "Operation.Write";
```

I shoud be able to get output as 1;

Or

if constants are defined like

```
const int Read=0;
const int Write=1;
```

If the input is

```
String str = "Read";
```

output should be 0

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the complete code to also Get the type of the Enum through Reflection without hardcoding it. The ParseConstant Method is also generic, s.t. you can use if for every Type.

```
    namespace MyNamgespace
{
    public enum Operation
    {
        Read = 0,
        Write
    }

    public class ClassWithConstants
    {
        public const int Read = 0;
        public const int Write = 1;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((ParseEnum("Operation.Write")));
            Console.WriteLine((ParseContant<ClassWithConstants>("Write")));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int ParseEnum(string enumValue)
        {
            var typeName = enumValue.Split('.')[0];
            var valueName = enumValue.Split('.')[1];

            var enumType = Type.GetType(string.Format("MyNamespace.{0}", typeName));
            var op = (Operation) Enum.Parse(enumType, valueName);

            return (int)op;
        }


        static int ParseContant<T>(string constantName)
        {
            var type = typeof (T);
            var field = type.GetField(constantName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            return (int)field.GetValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to have that functionality.

If we combine your proposals we can get something like this.

```
public static Operation getOperationByName(String name)  {
    return Enum.Parse(typeof(Operation),name);
}
```

Where the name should not be null and represent the name or position in enum ie

`"Read"` will return  `Operation.Rerad` and `"1"` will return `Operation.Write`

Answer (score 1):

`var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Operation), Operation.Write) //name = 'Write'`

`var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(Operation), "Write") //value = Operation.Write`

Comment: Why not just Operation.Write.GetName();  ?

Comment: that is the same method, it's a static method on the Enum type, that takes 2 arguments - a type, and a value.

Comment: Yes it is, my mistake with Java, there is normal, in C# you could create the extension.